# Format Number using Kibana Json Input

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I am using Kibana KPI Visualization, and showing sum of values, but those values are in million and billions.

I checked Advanced Settings under which we can apply the number formatting but that will be applied throughout the space, I want to apply at specific KPI.

I got a link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-json-input-convert-bytes-to-gb/231330/2 using which I can divide the number, but I want the numeraljs format to be applied like 0.00a, so that it can format the number automatically.

```
{"script": " _value / 1000"}
```

this can give in thousands, but if this formatting can be done using numeraljs format it would be great.

Any help is much appreciated!